# How to stop overwriting a file?

Tags: python, python-3.5

My program takes data that has been created during the course of the program, and at the end the user has a choice to export this data to a .txt file or not. If I enter a value for the FileName that already exists, the program should ask the user if they would like to overwrite the current .txt file. During my code, if I enter the value that already exists, it overwrites this data instead of following the next line of code. I have seen other articles saying to use "a" for append, but I don't see how this would have any relevance for this program.

(A temp file is already created earlier on in the program, and if the user chooses to export data, the file is simply renamed. If the user doesn't want to, it will delete the file.)

```
def export():
    fileName = input(FileNameText)
    exist = os.path.isfile(fileName)
    if exist == True:
        print("This file name already exists.")
        while True:
            try:
                overWrite = input("Would you like to overwrite the file? Y = yes, N = no\n")
                if overWrite == "Y":
                    break
                if overWrite == "N":
                    export()
                else:
                    invalidInput()
            except:
                invalidInput()
        os.rename("temp.txt",fileName+".txt")
    if exist == False:
        os.remove("temp.txt")
```

Comment: indent your code properly please

Comment: `os.rename` will fail if destination file already exists. You need `shutil.move`

Comment: whatever the user selects (overwrite or not) this script evaluate the line with os.rename in any case. You should rethink the logic from scratch here

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre 'shutil.move' makes the 'temp.txt' file that was created disappear...

Comment: @AlexGalpin Just debug the code in your head. See where the execution goes with the different options a.s.o. You are complicating your life without a reason.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That is not true on Posix systems.

Answer (score 2):

This should do just fine:

```
import os

while True:
    filename = input('Provide the file path::\n')
    if os.path.isfile(filename ):
        overwrite = input('File already exists. Overwrite? Y = yes, N = no\n')
        if overwrite.lower() == 'y':
            # call the function that writes the file here. use 'w' on the open handle
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your execution flow - your `break statement sends you out of the loop, and the first statement *after* the loop overwrites your file:

```
while True:
    try:
        overWrite = input("Would you like to overwrite the file? Y = yes, N = no\n")
        if overWrite == "Y":
            # this will send you out of the loop
            # to the point marked "here"
            break 
        if overWrite == "N":
            export()
        else:
            invalidInput()
    except:
        invalidInput()

# here
os.rename("temp.txt",fileName+".txt")
```